# Adding Arrays in to ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I can addAll array elements in to `ArrayList` by following two ways,

First,

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
list1.addAll(Arrays.asList("23,45,56,78".split(",")));
System.out.println(list1);
```

Second,

```
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
list2.addAll(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("23,45,56,78".split(","))));
System.out.println(list2);
```

Both works fine. And my question is Is there any difference between these two. And which one can be used for better practice Why ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both approaches produce the same result, so in that respect they are equivalent.

The second one, however, is wasteful. `Arrays.asList` does **not** allocate additional memory - it just wraps a given array in a `List`-like API. Creating a `new ArrayList`, on the other hand, allocates, albeit temporarily, another array with the same size, and copies all the values from the source array to the internal array of the `ArrayList`'s implementation.

With small arrays it's doubtful you'd even notice the difference, but the first approach is definitely more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

The [`addAll` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) is defined on the `Collection` interface.  With both examples, you are passing in a `List`.  You aren't keeping the `ArrayList` you're creating in the second example, but it's not even necessary.  `Arrays.asList` sends the `List` just fine into `addAll` by itself.  The creation of the unnecessary `ArrayList` in the second example is unnecessary, so the first example is preferred.

Answer (score 2):

Of the two you listed, the first is better. The second example creates another `ArrayList` object that isn't needed. Both would be functionally the same, but the first is more efficient.

As to the best practice, you can do this kind of thing in 1 line, not 2.

```
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("23,45,56,78".split(",")));
```

You can create a list by passing the arguments into it's constructor, a little cleaner than calling `.addAll` after creating the Object